# I want to calculate the MAX amount per ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, row-number

I am trying to get the MAX amount from Row# and I am stuck with this query.

```
SELECT [Member_Id]
    ,[Picked_Date]
    ,[Location_Number]
    ,[Refill_Amount]
    ,[Total_Refills_Permitted]
    ,[Quantity_Dispensed]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY Location_Number
        ,Member_Id ORDER BY Member_Id
            ,Picked_Date ASC
        ) AS Row#
FROM DummyTable
WHERE Row# IN (
        SELECT MAX(Row#)
        FROM DummyTable
        );
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would help.

Answer (score 1):

You are both partitioning and ordering by `Member_Id`.  Although allowed, this is unorthodox and including the column in the `order by` does nothing -- except make the ordering slightly slower and perhaps impede the use of an index in some cases.

If you want the most recent row, then:

```
select dt.*
from (select dt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Location_Number, Member_Id order by Picked_Date desc) as seqnum
      from dummytable dt
     ) dt
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you still need the `row#`, it is really the count.  So, this is an alternative:

```
select dt.*
from (select dt.*,
             count(*) over (partition by Location_Number, Member_Id) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by Location_Number, Member_Id order by Picked_Date desc) as seqnum
      from dummytable dt
     ) dt
where seqnum = cnt;
```